# Is there a way to determine which iphone charger is newer?

Tags: iphone, charger

I've got 2 chargers (both EU) here: One from an iPhone 7 and one from the 6. Both are almost identical in terms of look and labels, besides the manufacturer: one is flextronics the other one is salcomp.

I also know that there is a serial number inside the usb connector. There a way to decipher these and thereby determine the production date?

Comment: Buy a genuine, then look up the serial code.

Comment: Can you clarify if these are Apple branded chargers or knock off, third party, or other quality non-Apple hardware?

Comment: both are original apple chargers.

Comment: @OzzieSpin: Where do I look it up?

Comment: Put the serial code into google,

Comment: But TBH, the charging wall plug that came with my 4, charges my 6 with no problem